# Odd function with no critical points must be linear.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a **differentiable odd** function, i.e., $f(x) + f(-x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f^\prime(x)$ exists for all real $x$. Further assume the followings:

1. $
   \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty, \quad \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty.
   $
2. $f$ has no critical points on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e, $|f^\prime(x)|>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

One choice of such $f$ is $f(x) =x$. Do there exist any other choices of $f$ such that the above conditions hold.

It seems like the claim is true. I was initially trying to show that with first-order Taylor expansion, but it looks like it is getting me nowhere. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe $f(x)=x^3+x$? It is clearly odd and its derivative is $f'(x)=3x^2+1>0$

Comment: @NicolásVilches Yes. Thanks for the example. I should have checked the counter examples more thoroughly.